# Tiny inductors and capacitors connected in parallel to a DC motor terminals

Tags: capacitor, resistors, dc-motor

1. Why would you connect tiny resistors and capacitors in parallel to a DC motor as shown in the picture?
2. Why would two of the resistors be connected to the outer shell of the motor?

I checked the resistors and thy are around 0.5ohm or less and capacitors are 0.1uF.

I'd be grateful for approachable explanation as I know electronics only next to nothing.

[image]

Comment: Is it a DC or a AC motor?

Comment: The big "+" indicates DC motor. And the capacitive delta confirms it, they are there to suppress brush noise. (The "resistors" are probably inductors for further noise filtering.

Comment: In addition to Justme's answer: in a nutshell, this is done to keep the motor from becoming a radio transmitter (like, remember how you used to be able to hear your mobile phone in your radio speakers even though you weren't even on the phone? Sort of like that kind of interference...) As for "tiny", these parts are quite huge in terms of modern electronics. Nowadays you will often see grain-of-sand sized resistors and capacitors.

Comment: Those capacitors are almost certainly not 0.1 μF; I've never seen ceramic disc capacitors like that that were anywhere near that high capacitance. I'll be surprised if they're more than 0.001 μF.

Comment: @Sixtyfive than you for clarifying further

Comment: @Hearth, you are most probably right, I looked it up badly I  guess.

Comment: 0.1uF = 100nF and this is quite a normal package size for 100nF. See for example here: https://www.ebay.de/itm/334281273526

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. You wouldn't connect resistors. And they are not resistors. And they are not in parallel. They are inductors and they are in series with the motor.

   That is an LC filter to keep high frequency electromagnetic interference caused by the motor commutation from conducting back to power supply via wired or radiating via the wires and causing interference with nearby devices.
2. There are no resistors connected to metal shell, they are capacitors. The motor metallic shell has no connection to any voltage so the metal is a high impedance floating node. Floating nodes can act as antennas for the electromagnetic interference, as there are stray capacitances between metal chassis and structures inside the motor, so commutation noise may couple on to the metal shell. Capacitors are low impedance at high frequencies, so they shunt the AC signal so while the chassis still floats at DC, the capacitors act as short circuits to high frequency AC signals so it does not float at RF frequencies that radiate electromagnetic interference.

Comment: Awesome answer wow. I loved learning from this.

Answer (score 15):

These components are all for suppressing the EMI from the motor that will be generated by the brushes' intermittent contact on the commutator. Maybe the motor is being used in an audio application, for instance a turntable or tape transport.

There is one capacitor across the power terminals. This is to reduce noise between the supply lines.

There is one capacitor from each power terminal to the case. This is to reduce noise on the supply lines with respect to the case of the motor, which might be connected to the frame of the device it was intended for.

Those 'low value resistors' are probably inductors, to inhibit rapid changes of current in the supply.

Comment: Inrush current, say. Caps are also useful for suppressing sparking.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit below is a model of what you're seeing. The part within the dashed line represents the important parts of the motor: the windings of the rotor, with commutator switches. The rotor has several coils (inductors) in it, and they are switched in- and out- of the circuit by the commutator, denoted by the switches below.

Any time you turn on an inductor, it charges up magnetically and stores energy in the magnetic field (as opposed to electric field in the capacitors). When you turn the inductor off, the magnetic field that was driven by the current flowing in the inductor must now collapse. The energy that was stored in it has to be released as well. The inductor produces a voltage kick high enough to cause arcing across the now barely open commutator switches - all of this happens fast, and the rotor doesn't get a chance to turn very far in the meantime.

Those voltage spikes, as they generate arcing across the commutator, have rich frequency content - they are broadband radio interference noise sources. It is very important to suppress those, to stay within the legally mandated radio emission limits, and also to be nice to your nearby radio ham operator who will definitely hear your motor otherwise on their radio (!).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbUAIZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The inductors isolate high frequencies from propagating down the wires to towards the power source. The supply circuit would act as a loop antenna, rather nicely radiating the arc noise. The capacitors additionally shunt (short) the arc noise currents to keep them local to the motor. The currents are still there, but now we control where they flow. C2 is the differential mode short: it bypasses the part of the noise that flow between the commutator contacts. C1 and C3 are the common mode shorts: they bypass the noise that is common to both commutator switches, and redirect it back to the motor via the case. This works because the common mode noise is effectively connected between the case and both commutator contacts - it's capacitive coupling inside the motor. C1 and C3 capacitively couple this back to the outside of the case, closing the circuit.

The arcing of the commutator switches can be approximated by two square-wave ("broadband") voltage sources, running at the commutation frequency. Suppose the motor has 8 rotor windings, and rotates at 2400 RPM. The effective noise fundamental frequency would be 8 * 2400/60 = 8 * 40 = 320 Hz.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXNN8T.png)</sup>

The red loops are the common mode noise current loops: they flow from V2, through the internal parasitic capacitance to the case, then through common mode capacitors C1 and C3, back to V2.

The blue loop is the differential mode noise current loop: flows from V1, through the commutator, capacitor C2, and back to V1.

Comment: Wow, that's an impressive reply and as clear as can be. Thank you!

Answer (score -5):

I would guess we put tiny capacitors and resistors in parallel with the inductor to make better the transient response of the system. I am suspecting these values are chosen in order for the system to be critically damped which will help end the transient response as fast as possible.

Comment: How would they improve the transient response of the system, and what would be the "system" anyway?

Comment: The system is the DC motor in parallel with the tiny resistors and capacitors.

Comment: A "system" has an input and output, so you mean it improves the output of the motor? Also, there are no resistors, they are inductors, and the motor is not in parallel with them but in series.

Comment: @Justme the black box has a steady response and a transient response.The capacitors and resistors help to reduce the time in the transient response.

Comment: Sorry but there is no black box. It is unclear what exactly you mean. The transient response of what system, to what transients that are fed in, and what is the output of the system? And please note, there are no resistors at all in the circuit.

Comment: This could be true, except you'd need a motor so minuscule that a loupe would needed to see it - a much smaller motor than those capacitors, in terms of mechanical dimensions! The time constants of the capacitors and inductors involved are tiny compared to the mechanical time constants of the motor. So those devices don't do much when it comes to the electromechanical behavior of the motor. They do a lot when it comes to electromagnetic interference mitigation though. I like your "everything is a controls problem" approach, because it's partly true. Just mind the scales :)